# Can I hide images on Google Image Search that I've already flagged?

Tags: google-image-search, google-safesearch

When I'm reporting offensive images on Google, is it possible to hide images that I've already flagged? I want the images that I've flagged as offensive to disappear from my search results (instead of showing up again and again.)

Comment: To clarify, I keep seeing the images that I've flagged even when I reload the page after flagging the images.

Comment: I am also using the "safesearch moderate" search setting.

Comment: Those flagged images probably haven't been reviewed so that's why they will still show up. Don't think you can have them not appear until they are removed, if they are

Comment: Yes, that's why a web browser extension would be useful for this purpose. (Also, where can I make feature requests for improvements to Google Image Search?)

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot have an instant flag remove the image.  You can however set safeSearch to strict giving you a slimmer change of browsing offensive images.

Comment: Safesearch strict mode brings up a lot of false positives, so I'd prefer to stay with SafeSearch moderate. Also, I think this type of  feature (per-user image filtering) should be requested to Google - where can I make feature requests for Google Search improvements?

Comment: Are there any browser extensions that can remove specific images from search results (or prevent the loading of specific images?)